# Hibernate inserts child first in a one to one relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity `Parent` and an entity `Child`. The `Parent` has an embeddable id `ParentId` with only one string field. The `Child` can never exist without its parent so it has a composite primary key consisting of the foreign key to the `Parent` entity and an id itself for the child. I created a hibernate test case with the entity relations [here](https://github.com/mreilaender/hibernate-orm/blob/bce07add3533931eb6c17b88965c9b6972e04afa/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/jpa/test/OneToOneTest.java#L60).

For some reason, hibernate tries to insert the child entity first. How comes? In this case parent is the owning entity so I would expect it to be inserted first.

Comment: Don’t you need to set the back reference to Parent in your Child entity? Currently the „owning side“ is just modeld in the database. Therefore I assume that you need to explicitly set the parent entity to child as reference to model your use case. For example in addChild -> child.setParent(this)

Comment: I believe that's only if you were to make the association a bidirectional one, I want it to be unidirectional.

Comment: @LimitX I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Yeah I replaced the @EmbeddedId in the child, which included the ID of the parent, with a non embeddable ID.

Answer (score 0):

given the code from your repo

```
@Entity
static class Parent {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "id"))
    private final ParentId id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private final Collection<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    })
    private final Child child;
    ...
}
```

i believe the mapping is wrong. you should not have @OneToOne and @OneToMany towards the same Child @Entity: you should keep only one of them

Comment: I actually have a valid use case for having two relations, at least from a domain model perspective. But I'm starting to think with the design of the composite primary key, this will be impossible